# Connecting and updating Microsoft Azure SQL database on Mac with GTK C#

Tags: c#, sql, gtk

I am building an app in Visual Studio on a Mac 10.11.16 using GTK C#, and have a Microsoft Azure SQL database I'd like to edit from this app. Is there a way I can connect and edit the SQL tables with GTK#? I can't use .Net.

Comment: I guess the only way for me to get this working is to purchase a Microsoft device and build my app using .NET libraries.